# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filepath'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, typeerror

I don't know how to solve this error but I hope some of you guys know how to solve this issue.

**Error:**`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filepath'`

**Full error message:**

```
  File "train.py", line 167, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "train.py", line 113, in main
    checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback(),
  File "train.py", line 86, in checkpoint_callback
    return ModelCheckpoint(
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'filepath'
```

```
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

save_model_path = path/to/your/dir
def checkpoint_callback():
    return ModelCheckpoint(
        filepath= save_model_path,
        save_top_k=True,
        verbose=True,
        monitor='val_loss',
        mode='min',
        prefix=''
    )
```

Comment: Please add the *relevant* source code to the question itself.

Comment: You need to include an [mcve] in the question itself

Comment: I*ve added the source code in wich the error is caused. Just click on source  code(it's to big for stackoverflow)

Comment: if its too big for stackoverflow then thats not an [mcve]

Comment: ok I will add a minimal reproducible code

Comment: do you guys see it?

Comment: It wold seem that [ModelCheckpoint](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/blob/master/pytorch_lightning/callbacks/model_checkpoint.py#L42) does indeed not have a filepath argument..

Comment: what do you mean by that and do you have maybe a solution:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ModelCheckpoint` doesn't have a `filepath` keyword, it does however have a `dirpath` keyword (as you can see in the [documentation](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.html#pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint)), replace `filepath` with `dirpath`, like this:

```py
from pytorch_lightning.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

save_model_path = path/to/your/dir
def checkpoint_callback():
    return ModelCheckpoint(
        dirpath=save_model_path, # changed line
        save_top_k=True,
        verbose=True,
        monitor='val_loss',
        mode='min',
        prefix=''
    )
```

Comment: Or you he can fallback to the older version of pytorch. Looks like this code has changed recently.

Comment: fixed it for me I think

Comment: if you are still there could you help me out with another error real quick?

Comment: @saurabhbaid good to point out, didn't know about that!

Comment: @Scripter1 sure!

Comment: ok maybe we should write over discord? you can add me: SheeeshForce1#8083 if that is ok for you.

Comment: @Jason Rebelo Neves are you still there?

Comment: added, `igotinfected` on there @Scripter1

Answer (score 0):

The version of pytorch_lightning is too high or too low.
The api definition is changed

```py
CLASS pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint(dirpath=None, filename=None,
monitor=None, verbose=False, save_last=None, save_top_k=1, save_weights_only=False,
mode='min', auto_insert_metric_name=True, every_n_train_steps=None, train_time_interval=None,
every_n_epochs=None, save_on_train_epoch_end=None, period=None, every_n_val_epochs=None)
```